# App crashes on iPad 6.0.1 only

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, webview, crash

I've a very strange problem with my app. It runs perfectly on all Devices (even on iPad) running iOS 6.0. And with iOS 6.0.1 it runs also as expected on iPhone and iPod. But on iPad with 6.0.1 it crashes.

It's a very simple Single-View Application with a webView. This is my ViewControler.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://telefonecke.tumblr.com"];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webView loadRequest:req];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest             navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
    return NO;
}

return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

[_webView reload];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willEnterForeground) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self         name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)willEnterForeground {
    [_webView reload];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I actually don't know why it's not working, especially because it runs perfectly on iOS 6.0 and all other devices.

I'm thankful for every suggestion. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I also have a crash report, if it's helpful: [click here for the crash report](http://cargo.bplaced.net/cargo/temp..njrwusip.crash)

Comment: Symbolicate your crash log: `14  DieTelefonecke                 0x00084f4e 0x83000 + 8014`

Comment: I don't see any problem here, as this code works fine on my devices running iOS 6.0.1. The problem must rest elsewhere. To Till's point, symbolicate so we can see where it's crashing.

Comment: As an aside, I'm not sure why you're doing all of that stuff about reloading the view, adding the notification, etc., because the page is still there, but I assume you have a reason for that.

Comment: I dont know why but at the moment xcode won't symbolicate my crash log. I'll try to solve the problem as soon as possible. @Rob: I'm doing all that stuff because the website displayed in the webView is updating very often.

Comment: That line will symbolicate to the main functions call. Won't help.

Comment: If you're not doing clean builds, it's possible the 6.0 devices have older resources/Storyboards/Xibs that have different contents. Make sure to clean and test again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the symbolicated Last Exception Backtrace of your crash:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x327fb29e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x394dd97a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   UIKit                           0x38897d54 +[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:] + 436
3   UIKit                           0x386da406 -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 38
4   UIKit                           0x38563794 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 524
5   UIKit                           0x3850bc34 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1000
6   UIKit                           0x3850b6c8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
7   UIKit                           0x3850b116 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
8   GraphicsServices                0x35c8759e _PurpleEventCallback + 586
9   CoreFoundation                  0x327d067e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 10
10  CoreFoundation                  0x327cfee4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
11  CoreFoundation                  0x327cecb2 __CFRunLoopRun + 642
12  CoreFoundation                  0x32741eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
13  CoreFoundation                  0x32741d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
14  UIKit                           0x38562478 -[UIApplication _run] + 664
15  UIKit                           0x3855f2f4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
16  DieTelefonecke                  0x84f4e 0x83000 + 8014
```

Your apps call on `0x84f4e` is the main function, so nothing to worry about.

So it there is an exception happening when loading the main storyboard. That's where you should starting to look at, e.g. if the storyboard is part of the app bundle etc.

Comment: But how and what can I change at my storyboard? I mean it is xcode-generated.

Comment: Check the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html Exception is raised if the name is nil. I never used Storyboards, so I can't tell you why this is happening for you other than pointing at the documentation.